# Presto - Insert Array as Function Input

Tags: sql, group-by, presto

Per the [Presto Documentation](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html):

> approx_percentile(x, percentages) → array<[same as x]>
>   Returns the
>   approximate percentile for all input values of x at each of the
>   specified percentages. Each element of the percentages array must be
>   between zero and one, and the array must be constant for all input
>   rows.

---

I want to find the associated values of `amount` at the 25th, 50th, 75th, and 95th percentiles assuming the output would be an array but cannot figure out how to supply these values to the function *(outside of supplying one value)*.

I've tried various denotations that i'm used to seeing but I keep returning an error. How do I input many values to get the array output?

```
APPROX_PERCENTILE(amount, .25, .50, .75, .95)

APPROX_PERCENTILE(amount, (.25, .50, .75, .95))

APPROX_PERCENTILE(amount, {.25, .50, .75, .95})

APPROX_PERCENTILE(amount, [.25, .50, .75, .95])   '<--- I assumed this was the proper way

APPROX_PERCENTILE(amount, <[.25, .50, .75, .95]>)

APPROX_PERCENTILE(amount, <.25, .50, .75, .95>)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just figured it out - the proper way to input an array as a function parameter is:

```
APPROX_PERCENTILE(amount, ARRAY[0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 0.95])
```